# can you use git flow (the idea) without actually using the commands?

Tags: git, git-flow

How big is the advantage of using the git-flow command set (which need to be installed) vs. just working with master, develop and feature branches (i.e. following the *idea* of git flow except for release and hotfix branches)?

Are the commands (e.g.`git flow feature start feature_branch`) really just simplified versions of the longer regular git commands (in this case `git checkout develop` and `git checkout -b feature_branch`)?

*Background: Team is used to git commands. Basically follows the idea of using master/develop/feature branch. Why would it switch to to the git-flow commands?*

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment instead of an answer because I can't speak to the particular advantages of dedicated git-flow commands. (I wasn't even aware there *were* dedicated git-flow commands.) But, yes, they would just be higher-level wrappers over vanilla Git, and you could certainly use vanilla Git instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-flow` commands are just "command sugar" to make it easier to follow Git Flow workflow and under the hood they call one or more bare `git` commands per step. You can find various tables on Internet that map `git-flow` commands to bare `git` (for example this https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac).

So if your team mates know what commands to execute in every step of workflow you don't need to use `git-flow` at all, it's just easier for those who don't remember those commands.